# ModuleNotFoundError in absolute folder structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

This may be answered somewhere else but I cannot find a solution.

I have these two folder structures:

```
app/
  service/
    __init__.py
    caller.py
    ...
  utils/
    __init_.py
    config.py
    ...
  __init__.py
  ...
```

In `caller.py` I have:

```
from app.utils import config
```

When I run `python caller.py` (from `cd` to `app/service`) I get:

```
from app.utils import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

However, if I move `caller.py` to the `app` folder and use the following import line:

```
from utils import config
```

It works. Why? I've also tried using `.app.utils`, `..utils`, etc., but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: No, the closest answer is the one that mentions `from application.app.folder.file import func_name` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: When running `caller.py` after moving the file to `app`, are you still in `app/service/`?

Comment: does `from ..utils import config ` work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the parent directory to the path, then when changing into directory "/app/service", Python will find the neighboring "utils" directory.

### caller.py

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, '../')

from utils import config

print(f"Caller imported config value SETTING_X: {config.SETTING_X}")
```

### config.py

```
SETTING_X = 42
```

#### Output

```
Caller imported config value SETTING_X: 42
```